# asymptotic local analysis of $y' − \frac{y}{x} = \cos x$ as $x → 0+$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics

Find the leading behavior of solutions to $y' − \frac{y}{x} = \cos x$ as $x → 0+$. Show that the leading behavior is determined by a three-term dominant balance.

My thought is for homogeneous part, $y' - \frac{y}{x} = 0$, the solution is $y = cx$.

And for the particular solution, expand $ \cos x $ by Taylor expansion and at the first step, I try to find $y_p(x) = s(x)$ such that $s'(x) − \frac{s(x)}{x}\sim 1$ then $y_p(x) = s(x) + c(x)$ to find $(s(x)+c(x))' − \frac{s(x)+c(x)}{x}\sim 1 - \frac{x^2}{2}$, and continue this process.

But in the first step, if $\frac{s(x)}{x}\sim -1$, then $s(x)\sim -x$, and $s'(x)\sim-1$ witch is not asymptotically smaller than $\frac{s(x)}{x}$ or $1$.

If $s'(x)\sim 1$, $s(x)\sim x$, then $\frac{s(x)}{x}$ is not asymptotically smaller than $s'(x)$ or $1$.

If $\frac{s(x)}{x}\sim s'(x)$, $s(x)\sim \text{const} \cdot x$, $s'(x)\sim \text{const}$, then $0 \sim 1$, which is not possible, so I don't know how can I apply dominant balance here to get the asymptotic leading terms, thank you for any help.

Comment: You can divide the equation by $x$ to get exact differential equation

Comment: Both in the original and in the equation for $s$. That in the limit to 0 you get with the assumption of "$s$ differentiable there" $s'(0)-\lim_{x\to 0}s'(x)\sim 1$ just means that the assumption of a differentiable $s$ was wrong. /// Perhaps this equation is too simple to see the use of the balancing approach, as a more direct computation is readily accessible.

Comment: @AdityaDwivedi thank you, i didnt notice that, but i am still confused why the dominant balance does not work here, because in class, the professor only showed us how to use it to solve this kind of problem and for the exact differential equation, i have to get some asymptotic expansion for $\int \frac{cosx}{x}$ to get the leading term of the particular solution of y right, how can i do that.

Comment: You might be able to apply the balancing approach to the equation for $v=y'$, as $$xy'-y=x\cos x\implies xv'=xy''=\cos x-x\sin(x).$$

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I get it right now, but with the help of Aditya Dwivedi and Lutz Lehann, I tried to get the exact differential equation: $(\frac{y}{x})' = \frac{\cos(x)}{x}$ and from wolfram, I get the leading term of y should be $x \ln x$, so I understand now why in the problem, it says the leading behavior is determined by a three-term dominant balance. when I try $s(x)' - \frac{s}{x} \sim 1$, I can get $s(x) \sim x \ln x$, so $y = x \ln x + c(x)$ and then I can approach to the next step.

Comment: Use \cos, \ln, \sim, to produce $\cos$, $\ln$ and $\sim$.

Comment: "leading term of f" $\to$ "leading term of $y$"

Comment: @Gary Thank you. Although I used latex before, I am ashamed that I did not know these before......